# Nuxt ignore functions folder when building project for cypress tests

Tags: nuxt.js, cypress

In our **Nuxt (Version 2.15.8)** project there is a **functions folder** within the root directory. It includes the firebase functions files. During the CI process (Github Actions) we run a **Cypress (9.6.1)** test.
Unfortunately, the test fails due to some TypeErrors inside the functions. These errors dont affect the functions and are fixable.
However, I wondered whether there is a way to ignore the functions folder because it is completely independent of the main application which is tested with Cypress.

I searched the Nuxt2 docs and found the .nuxtignore file and a few other methods. But as per the docs these methods only work for files inside the layout, store, pages and middleware files.

Does someone know a different approach?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a typescript error no? Setting those in the configuration of your CI should be the solution IMO.

Comment: Yes this would be a viable option. As I mentioned, the errors themselves are not difficult to fix. I would be interested in a way to exclude those files in the nuxt build process